# Having problem in this very basic PYTHON program

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i am making a very simple python program which takes a string as input from user and adds a '-' between every character but the problem is it adds it to last one too but i don't want that...

Here's the code:

```
string = input("Enter the string to be traversed: ")
for ch in string:
    print(ch , end = "-")
```

Output:

```
Enter the string to be traversed: helloworld
h-e-l-l-o-w-o-r-l-d-
```

I don't want it to print '-' after the last character...

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem and there is a string method to deal with it. Instead of a for loop, join the characters with a dash.

```
string = input("Enter the string to be traversed: ")
print("-".join(string))
```

`.join` will work with anything that iterates strings. In your case, a string does that, character by character. But a list or tuple would work as well.